# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Products' not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, so I am trying to store some information coming from a form and I am getting this error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Products' not found

I have tried adding `use products;` but it still doesn't work...

Here is my code:

#### Products Controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
class ProductsController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user_id = Session::get('user_id');
        //die(var_dump($user_id));

        return Products::create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'id_template' => $data['id_template'],
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'metadescription' => $data['metadescription'],
            'robots' => $data['robots'],
            'canonical' => $data['canonical'],
            'product_name' => $data['product_name'],
            'product_image' => $data['product_image'],
            'product_code' => $data['product_code'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'price_discount' => $data['price_discount'],
            'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
            'summary' => $data['summary'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'friendly_url' => $data['friendly_url'],
            'contact_form' => $data['contact_form'],
            'rating' => $data['rating'],
            'comments' => $data['comments'],
            'discount' => $data['discount'],
            'show' => $data['show'],
            'active' => $data['active'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### Products model

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your `routes.php` look like?

Comment: In your Products class name and file name are different ..pleae change it - class Products extends Model

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? The given error message does not look related to Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller write:

```php
use App\products;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You will need to write **products** in upper case -> **Products** as your **Class** name and **File** name.
2. Import your Product Model: `use App\Products;` in your Controller

Comment: Hello @Aless55 i just did it

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;
use App\Products;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

and put the products in uppercase -> class Products extends Model

and got this error:

Error
Class 'App\Products' not found

Comment: @SolarConfinement Is the file name of the Product Model also in upper case and singular?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller import Products Model like this:

```php
use App\Products; // Import in controller

return \App\Products::create([]); // not want to import in controller
```

In Products Model - Model file name and Class name are same.

```php
class Products extends Model {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to import Products model into the controller

```
use App\Products;
```

and change your Products model into

```
class Products extends Model
{
    //
}
```

i would recommend installing PHP Intelephense extension so that you can automatically import the Models you are using in your controller